# Django extensions/werkzeug runserver_plus crashes with exit 247 when catching an error

Tags: python, django, werkzeug, django-extensions

This issue just appeared a few weeks ago and I haven't been able to track it down or fix it.  I always use `runserver_plus` for the dev server so that I can use the werkzeug debugger.  However, for some reason, now whenever there's an exception, instead of properly displaying the werkzeug debug page, `runserver_plus` crashes.

First, the only the HTML of the page is loaded:
[image]

Then the server itself crashes:
[image]

I am on Mac OS X (latest version).  I have not been able to track down what that exit code 247 means--it only appears when I run it in PyCharm.  The server does also crash if I run it outside of PyCharm, but without telling me the status code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm still not sure what exactly the nature of the problems was, I realized finally that this issue only occurred when within `LOGGING` within `settings.py`, I had the `'mail_admins'` handler enabled and it included the settings `'include_html': True`.

No idea why this is the case, but once I turned off `include_html`, the Werkzeug debugger worked as expected.